# Rails tests skipping custom validations or custom validation not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, attributes

I have a model `Subscription` with a boolean attribute `:fee` which should not be modified after the creation of a `Subscription`.

I added a custom validation like this:

```
validate :fee_not_changed

def fee_not_changed
  return unless created_at != updated_at && fee_changed?

  errors.add :fee, :changed, message: "cannot be changed"
end
```

Our API is not allowing us to update `:fee` (the error is returned) but I can update the attribute in tests despite the custom validation like so:

```
test "fee cant be edited after creation" do
  subscription = subscriptions(:with_fee)
  subscription.update!(fee: false)

  assert_not subscription.saved_change_to_fee?
end

Expected true to be nil or false
```

Also, if I put a `byebug` before the assertion, I can see that it effectively updates the attribute skipping the custom validation.

What's the problem? Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Can you also share the fixture? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a **caching** issue.

Can you try reloading the subscription with `.reload`?

`assert_not subscription.reload.saved_change_to_fee?`